# Wicket DropDownChoice Integer

Tags: wicket-1.5, dropdownchoice

I have problem with Wicket DropDownChoice. The DropDownChoice does not show values for Integer.
wicket version: 1.5.7

```
DropDownChoice<Integer> rEvalFormVersion = new DropDownChoice<Integer>("evalForm.version", EVAL_FORM_VERSIONS);
```

where EVAL_FORM_VERSIONS is list of versions.

For example: In the list are two versions, DropDownChoice is populated by two choices but nothing is shown.
Btw: Another data types work good.

In the near future we will update Wicket to a new version. Is this problem in Wicket 6 or can I simply just wait for new version?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [wicket examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?1&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.DropDownChoicePage) (and from experience) this should simply work. In the example they do define an IChoiceRenderer for the DropDownChoice.